# Can I plot ONLY consecutive minutes in a dataset with a broken time series?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I want to be able to connect the dots on these plots, but I ONLY want to connect plots where the timeseries difference is consecutive (**1-minute intervals**).  What I did was pulled specific points of interest from a time-series database using masking method in Python and Pandas dataframe, and plotted them with plotly.  When the data is in 1-minute intervals, they look very close together on a plot.  Here's what the plots currently look like.
[image]

I can't seem to find any way to do this except for this reference to put "None" in between the consecutive parts. I know I could do a for-loop and add "None" inbetween the data when the timedelta is > 1 minute, but I was hoping plotly has some way to just do this by setting a parameter on the X-Axis intervals.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=[10, 20, None, 15, 10, 5, 15, None, 20, 10, 10, 15, 25, 20, 10],
    name = '<b>No</b> Gaps', # Style name/legend entry with html tags
    connectgaps=True # override default to connect the gaps
```

The gaps on the red lines are an example of what I want the plot to look like. Snagged from the plotly docs.
[image]

Comment: It would help to see your code and some data.  I *think* the way to go about this is when you do your masking in python/pandas put the `None` in there then.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for. "I want to do what's in the documentation, but without those steps" questions are generally frowned upon. Are you looking for advice on how to insert the `None` values at scale? Is there a reason you can't have missing values in your trace? Are you trying to do some manipulation of the individual segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# The idea is to create a consecutive set where missing pieces are `nan`

import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# ----- this is to create sample data -----

timeX = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01 00:00',
    '2020-01-01 00:01',
    '2020-01-01 00:02',  #mind the gap
    '2020-01-01 00:05',
    '2020-01-01 00:06',  #mind the gap
    '2020-01-01 00:11',
    '2020-01-01 00:12',
    '2020-01-01 00:13'])
valuesY = [2,3,2,4,5,3,1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[timeX,valuesY]).T
df.columns = ['timeX','valuesY']

# ------ here I create a consecutive range (of minutes) ----

startX = min(df['timeX'])
endX = max(df['timeX'])
daterange = pd.date_range(start=startX,end=endX,freq='1Min')
ef = pd.DataFrame(data=daterange, columns=['timeX'])

# ------ by merging with left join on timeX missing matches become nan

ef = ef.merge(df, on='timeX', how='left')

# ------ eliminating the connectgaps feature shows the connected parts only

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
    x=ef['timeX'],
    y=ef['valuesY'],
    name = 'with Gaps')) # override default to connect the gaps

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exaclty the help I needed!  Magic trick here is merging the columns to force nan values.  Genius!

Answer (score 0):

*If* plotly had an option specifically for this, I would expect to find it [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-marker-line), [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattergl/#scattergl-line), or in one of the other sections on that page, but I don't see anything close to this. (Granted, I've only skimmed, but what you're looking for is more specific than what plotly and similar packages usually support.)

The insertion of `None` would probably be my first choice in generating such plots. If you want more control over separate line segments, you could try something like

1. split the data into segments (itself an involved procedure), with each segment becoming a separate trace / Scatter instance in the figure's list of traces. (I usually prefer to use the `go.Figure(data=[<list of traces>])` format rather than calls to `Figure.add_trace()`, but YMMV.)
2. Use [`legendgroup`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattergl/#scattergl-legendgroup) and `showlegend` and `line` options to make the different segments *look* like the same trace to the viewer, but actually be separate traces internally.